# What happens if you accidently flag a post incorrectly?

Tags: support, flags, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag removal: Is it possible to remove your flag or otherwise indicate it should be unflagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should)

I was just  doing "my bit" on SO and was flagging a series of answers as spam... I got a little over-zealous and accidently flagged [Facebook friend counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232288/php-facebook-friend-counter/13128143#13128143) as spam, and it's not... Is there anyway to retract a flag? Or, do I just have to stick with looking like a plonker?

Comment: A mod will decline the flag that's all.

Comment: Oh you plonker! Look everybody, what a plonker! OMG. :P Nah, sh*t happens. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tim Post comes to your house and beats you to death with a giant flag.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127992/why-dont-moderators-see-who-flagged-a-post-as-spam/151909#151909)

Naw; whatever moderator handles it ends up rolling their eyes and dismissing it. [No one  even sees your name on spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127992/why-dont-moderators-see-who-flagged-a-post-as-spam) - so your mistake gets chalked up to the big "SO users click things randomly" tally and folks get on with their lives.

#### See: [Flag removal: Is it possible to remove your flag or otherwise indicate it should be unflagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should)